# Looking for an exposition of the proof of the LMN theorem

Tags: circuit-complexity, boolean-functions, lg.learning, pseudorandomness, pseudorandom-generators

Is there any lecture note or review paper which gives a self-contained proof of the Linial-Mansour-Nisan theorem?

---

The exposition of that in Ryan O'Donnel's book seems to use terminology and notation which isn't easy to parse unless one reads many pages before that. Most lecture notes I found only at best mention it in the passing.

Comment: I find the original paper readable (http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~ehudf/courses/anal09/LMN.pdf). It is almost self-contained except for Haståd's Switching Lemma which can be considered as classical now and for which you can find numerous resources (his thesis for example).